# Composer create-project. Point at specific branch

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I have created a fork of the Laravel repo, made some changes to it and renamed the name in the composer file to votemike/laravel. I would now like to create a new project based on this repo and so I'm calling:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist votemike/laravel --repository='{"type":"vcs","url":"https://github.com/votemike/laravel"}' testing
```

However, my terminal then pops up saying `Reading composer.json of votemike/laravel (v5.2.23)` which gradually decrements. The resulting project then seems to be a normal Laravel project without my changes.
I then tried:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist votemike/laravel:master --repository='{"type":"vcs","url":"https://github.com/votemike/laravel"}' testing
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.

Could anyone help me out with the command I need to run? I assume my computer shouldn't be reading every version of the composer file. And can the command be simplified at all?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 7):

Update:

Since this is a custom Composer project, I wonder if you could use the custom create project script that I wrote a blog post about : [Composer create project script](https://jacmoe.dk/blog/2016/january/composer-create-project-script)

You simply drop it at the root of your project, edit it to match, and run it - and it will create a project for you.

I've used it to test my own Composer projects, and I think it could allow you to simply create your custom Laravel projects without having to fight with Composer over versions.

https://gist.github.com/jacmoe/e9e8ed5fd45affb893a8

Edit:

What you need to do is edit this:

```
BRANCH_NAME=${1:-master}
DEST_DIR=${2:-~/Desktop/newapp}
PACKAGE_NAME=vendor/package
```

You can probably leave the first ( `BRANCH_NAME` ) as-is, but do change `DEST_DIR` and `PACKAGE_NAME` !

`PACKAGE_NAME` *must* match the package name of the `composer.json` for your modified Laravel source directory.

**Notice** :

You use this from your locally cloned copy of your fork of Laravel - it works *locally* - it does not try to find anything on Github or Packagist. It is using the directory you are in (working directory) and will use that to create a project - you can choose where the script will create it.

---

*Original answer:*

Off the top of my head:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev votemike/laravel
```

Or, if that doesn't work, try this:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev votemike/laravel:dev-master
```

Alternatively, instead of `dev-master` , use `@dev` - or `dev-branch` ...

The first command should do it, though.

Does your cloned project have any tags? If it doesn't, that would explain why Composer is acting up. Telling it to use `dev-master` will fix that, because Composer will by default only pull releases (tags following the major.minor.revision scheme).

Edit:

In one of my projects I am using the master branch of a package, using the following entry in my `composer.json` :

```
"jacmoe/yii2-tale-jade": "dev-master",
```

How you get your package into your composer.json is up to you - either manually, or by requiring it using the right version ( like `dev-master` )

This requires that the *composer.json* for the project you are trying to require is not using a *version* field - if it does have one, remove it.

Comment: The project has the tags from the original Laravel repo, I haven't added any more. Does that mean I need to create a new tag each time I push? Is there not a way to just use the HEAD of master? Will creating a new branch with a specific name help anything?

Comment: `--stability=dev` should do that. Otherwise add `:@dev` or `:dev-master` to the package name :)

Comment: Running your suggestion results in the error `Could not find package votemike/laravel with version @dev.`  
I don't understand where stability or dev-master is defined in the repo I'm trying to create the project from.  
Do I need to adjust my composer file some more?   https://github.com/votemike/laravel/blob/3e0e84db9f141dc52a342b8c143e077919a4fd78/composer.json

Comment: I am going to update my answer with a different approach :)

Comment: I see where you are going with that approach. But that assume I already have a composer.json file. However, I'm using the create-project command for a brand new project. I have a feeling I need to add a packages.json file of some sort...

Comment: @Votemike That script will create a new project for you - all that it requires is that you put it in the source directory - which is your cloned/modifed Laravel repository :)

Comment: You can try to add `  "minimum-stability": "dev",` to that composer.json - otherwise it looks OK.

Comment: Through your help with the dev-master I settled upon `composer create-project votemike/laravel:dev-master --repository='{"type":"vcs","url":"https://github.com/votemike/laravel"}' testing`. Thanks